# iTunes syncs only one songs from each album

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have about 7 GB worth of music, all complete albums, that I'm trying to sync on my phone. I select `Entire music library` and hit apply. Before I hit apply, it shows me 27 GB free on my iPhone. Then, it finishes the copying process way too quickly. After the sync completes, it says 34 GB free, and there is only one song per album. I tried choosing the artists and albums individually, removing all music and re-synching, and nothing worked. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in iTunes. Restarting iTunes and re-syncing solved the problem.